# Filter data from an variables and store into another one in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my code

```
<?php 

    $content = "Hello Guys how are you @[6] i hope you are doing well @[9]";

    $tags = ""; // Value under @[]

    echo $tags;

 ?>
```

i want to store value under @[] to $tags separated with comma

Comment: So what is your question? This is just a statement of intent!

Comment: You want to replace viku(the username) with 003(user id) at the point of inserting data to db?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RiggsFolly i want to store @[3] in other filed of table in database?

Comment: Ok, so write another query to do that and execute it

Comment: @BobbyAxe no i just want to add the userid of VIKU in other filed called tags in table of database

Comment: @RiggsFolly how to filter that... cause thats variable contains some text after that user id

Comment: Example : i have variable $content="hello this is test @[7]" i need $tags=7;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all`[[1](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match-all.php)] to get the content between all `@[]` parts. Then `implode`[[2](http://php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php)] the result to get a comma seperated string.

```
<?php

define('FIRST_MATCH_GROUP', 1);

$content = "Hello Guys how are you @[6] i hope you are doing well @[9]";
$tags = [];
preg_match_all("/@\[(.)\]/", $content, $tags); // Value under @[]

$tags = implode(',', $tags[FIRST_MATCH_GROUP]);

var_dump($tags);
```

Working example:

https://3v4l.org/7kYH6

> **Output for 5.6.38 - 7.3.0rc3**
>
> string(3) "6,9"

Regex explanation:

https://regex101.com/r/cxH6L3/1/

> /@[(.)]/
>
> @ matches the character @ literally (case sensitive)
>
> \[ matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
>
> 1st Capturing Group (.)
>
> . matches any character (except for line terminators)
>
> \] matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)

**EDIT:** For multiple numbers between `@[]` you would have to adjust the regex to `@\[(.+)\]` and add an Ungreedy flag, see https://regex101.com/r/cxH6L3/2 and https://3v4l.org/aj0Ln

Comment: But what if we have more then one digit value in @[] it doesn't recognize it... @Xatenev

Comment: Thanks again @Xatenev